# SQL Trying to select only the first record out of several returned

Tags: sql

I have a query that returns students and their roommates.  The idea is to have everyone show up in the first column and then column 2 and 3 to have each roommate.  Column 3 could be blank, but columns 1 and 2 will always have results.

My query is returning the correct data with the exception of when I there are 3 people in the room, I will get more than one record. such as below.

```
_roommate1  roommate2 roommate3  room1_   
_roommate1  roommate3 roommate2  room1_  
_roommate2  roommate1 roommate3  room1_  
_roommate2  roommate3 roommate1  room1_   
_roommate3  roommate1 roommate2  room1_  
_roommate3  roommate2 roommate1  room1_
```

All I want to do is keep the first instance of each row when the field is appears in column 1.

so I would like to reduce the output to:

```
_roommate1  roommate2 roommate3  room1_  
_roommate2  roommate1 roommate3  room1_  
_roommate3  roommate1 roommate2  room1_
```

The intent is to send a form letter to each person in  column 1 to tell them the names of their roommates.

Since I can only use distinct on a row and not on a field, I am at a temporary loss as how I might be able to do this. What I would like to be able to do is say if it worked is:

`SELECT (DISTINCT Column1), column2, column3` so i would only get the first instance of each column1.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251278/select-one-column-distinct-sql

Comment: can you include the query you are using to generate your sample output?

Comment: Could you give us a stripped-down version of your tables, as well, please?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a GROUP BY might be useful?

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: It might, but the referenced page does not supply enough information for me to solve my particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Column1, MAX(Column2) AS Column2, MAX(Column3) AS Column3
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Column1
```

Comment: That'll return a sinle row per student, being: `_roommate1  roommate3 roommate3  room1_`

Comment: This will give one row per student, but does not solve the problem of showing roommate2 and roommate3 as separate entries.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm obviously confused.  First, to see if I can correct my first try.  In the SELECT clause, if Column 2 is changed to `MIN(Column2) AS Column2`, does that address the problem?

If that doesn't work, can you tell us if you are using SQL Server, MySql, Oracle, other?

Answer (score -1):

It's a crazy question.  You're doing something wrong.  Why do you need to execute this query?  Break this up into multiple queries and aggregate the data in your programming.  It seems you're asking the database to do something non-standard and strange.

Comment: I guess that means you don't have a solution?

Comment: You didn't offer a problem.  You just said that you had a query that's not working.  What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Databases are much quicker handling data than scripting languages, so heavy lifting (i.e. data aggregation, filtering) should be handled by them.