# SQL Separating Distinct Values using single column

Tags: sql, distinct

Does anyone happen to know a way of basically taking the 'Distinct' command but only using it on a single column. For lack of example, something similar to this:

```
        Select (Distinct ID), Name, Term from Table
```

So it would get rid of row with duplicate ID's but still use the other column information. I would use distinct on the full query but the rows are all different due to certain columns data set. And I would need to output only the top most term between the two duplicates:

```
ID  Name    Term
1   Suzy    A
1   Suzy    B
2   John    A
2   John    B
3   Pete    A
4   Carl    A
5   Sally   B
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: possbile duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251278/select-one-column-distinct-sql

Comment: Try `SELECT ID, MIN(Name), MIN(Term) FROM Table GROUP BY ID`.

Comment: So suppose you have id = 1 and id =2, name = Suzy, name = Suzy, and Term = A and Term = B. (eg {1,Suzy,A}, {2, Suzy, B}).  You want to keep only one id, the one whose id occurs first, and still show two rows. Why not just use MIN(Id) AS ID and group by name and term?

Comment: Yes correct. I would only want to Keep  {1, Suzy, A} in that case. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 to answer the first guys question. I will try this Min() solution you both suggested. Thanks

Comment: Using the Min aggregate and Group by worked great, I was able to accomplish the output I wanted. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.Id, t.Name, t.Term
from (select distinct ID from Table order by id, term) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row number for this

```
Select ID, Name, Term from(
   Select ID, Name, Term,  ROW_NUMBER ( ) 
    OVER ( PARTITION BY ID order by Name) as rn from Table
Where rn = 1) 
as tbl
```

Order by determines the order from which the first row will be picked.